# Failure to install npm install after removing node packages and making githup repo private

Tags: node.js, git, github

Github newbie.
I subscribe to github and using it for for saving my version-controlled files. I then removed all node packages and run npm install. NO INSTALLATION OCCURS AND I GET THE FOLLOWING ERRORS:

```
J:\workspace\epimss\angular2\ts\com-epimss.ng2.ts>npm install
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror htt
ps://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps.git C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-http
s-github-com-floridoo-gulp-sourcemaps-git-master-2c8ed5d4: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\my-user\App
Data\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-floridoo-gulp-sourcemaps-git-master-2c8ed5d4'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror htt
ps://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps.git C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-http
s-github-com-floridoo-gulp-sourcemaps-git-master-2c8ed5d4: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-
sourcemaps.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror htt
ps://github.com/SitePen/remap-istanbul.git C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-
github-com-SitePen-remap-istanbul-git-master-a24313ec: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\my-user\AppData
\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-SitePen-remap-istanbul-git-master-a24313ec'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror htt
ps://github.com/SitePen/remap-istanbul.git C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-
github-com-SitePen-remap-istanbul-git-master-a24313ec: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/SitePen/remap-ista
nbul.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "P:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "P:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "
install"
npm ERR! node v5.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cac
he\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps.git C:\Users\my-user\AppData\
Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-floridoo-gulp-sourcemaps-git-master-2c8ed5d4
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-gith
ub-com-floridoo-gulp-sourcemaps-git-master-2c8ed5d4'...
npm ERR! fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps.git/': Failed to connect to github.com
port 443: Timed out
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     J:\workspace\epimss\angular2\ts\com-epimss.ng2.ts\npm-debug.log
```

Is there a way to make this work or I will have to remove github? Is the latter is the case please se how.

Thanks

Comment: seems like timeout issue. can you access `https://github.com` from your browser? if yes, then, is it possible for you to ping the url?

Comment: I can access `https://github.com`. However when I do `ping https://github.com` I received the output `Ping request could not find host https://github.com. Please check the name and try again.` So the ping request did not work. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: hmm are you using any proxy server for the internet connection?